# keyboardAppearance with blue color numbers IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboardtype

I want keyboard with number pad and numbers with blue color. I am using

```
myTextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
```

with

```
UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad
```

It's giving numbered keypad with black numbers. How I can get blue color numbers?
I am getting :
[image]

But I want these 1,2,3 numbers in blue color. How I can get it?

Comment: You can't without creating your own custom keyboard.

Comment: I think that you need to implement your custom keyboard

Comment: Demo but it's in swift maybe it will help you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be customised on Apple's default keyboard implementation. If you'd like to, you can go down the path of creating your own, or searching for an open source keyboard control that supports this.

However: I'd strongly advise against doing this for something as simple as changing the color of the numbers. iOS users are accustomed to the default keyboard, and presenting them something else could be confusing when unnecessary.